# Ckeditor newpage check for document change

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to make newpage plugin to check if document has changed before clearing the document?
This is to prevent losing all work if accidentally pressing newpage icon

Answer (score 1):

```
editor1.on('beforeCommandExec', function(evt) {
    if (evt.data.name == 'newpage') {
        if (evt.editor.checkDirty()) {
            return confirm('You have unsaved work. Do you want to start a new page anyway?');
        }
    }
});

editor1.on('afterCommandExec', function(evt) {
    if (evt.data.name == 'newpage') {
        evt.editor.resetDirty();
    }
});
```